# Left and Right Eigenvectors - when are they the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Under what circumstances is any left eigenvector of a matrix also a right eigenvector (and vice versa)? 
My guess is that this is true if the matrix is symmetric, but is this necessary, and is it sufficient? Actually I never had attended a course in linear algebra, so please be patient with me.

Comment: You confuse left/right eigenvector and singular vectors of a matrix (these are different notions). You seem to talk about eigenvector here, but please clarify this point.

Comment: @Surb: Why do you think so?

Comment: @joriki Well, what I know, is that $x\neq 0$ is a left eigenvector of $A$ if $A^Tx=\lambda x$, $y\neq 0$ is a right eigenvector of $A$ if $Ay=\lambda y$ and $(u,v)$ is a singular vector (actually it is a family of singular vectors) of $A$ if $Au = \lambda v$ *and* $A^Tv = \lambda u$... Thus (to the best of my knowledge), there is no notion of left/right singular vector. BTW, why don't you think so ?

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed confusing the notions, and I aim to talk about eigenvectors of course!

Comment: @Surb: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) speaks of left and right singular vectors of a matrix.

Comment: @joriki ok... I did not know that... so basically as in the eigenvalue case, the  "left" singular vectors are the singular vectors of the transpose matrix. In any case, symmetry is a sufficient condition for both (the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors). I'm not sure if it's necessary though (I would not be surprised that a counter-example could be given with a matrix which is not diagonalisable).

Comment: @user136457 can you show that it is sufficient ? (using the definitions I recalled in my second comment)

Comment: $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is a counterexample.  It has eigenvalues $\pm i$.  Since $A^T = -A$, the eigenvectors of $A$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $A^T$ with switched eigenvalues.

If we want $A$ and $A^T$ to have the same eigenvectors with the same corresponding eigenvalues, this is a little trickier.  There are counterexamples for complex matrices, but perhaps not for real ones.

Comment: @Surb what do you mean by "both" when you say "In any case, symmetry is a sufficient condition for both (the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors)."

Comment: And what was the verdict? are left and right singular vectors actually different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A real matrix $A$ is normal, that is $AA^T = A^TA$, if and only if it is orthogonal diagonalizable. In that case, the left eigenvectors are also right eigenvectors. I suspect it will be necessary too.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Does someone has an easy proof for that or a reference?

Comment: It is a standard result. You can find it most books on linear algebra or numeric. Wikipedia has some reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: Can you point me to a proof that "it is necessary too"?